# Which method for handling changes on OnPush?

Tags: angular

I want to use `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`.
My question is which method to choose for `Input` change?

## Setters and getters

```
private _someVariable: number;

@Input() set someVariable(i) {
    this._someVariable = i;
    // something to do
}

get someVariable() {
    return this._someVariable;
}
```

There is a lot of boilerplate and some variables may be set before other which can cause problems. 
I think that method is often used by `Angular Material` team.

## OnChanges

```
ngOnChanges(e) {
    if (e.someVariable && !e.someVariable.firstChange) {
      this.someVariable = e.someVariable.currentValue;
      // something to do
    }
}
```

I think it was design for it, but there is problem with `firstChange`, which You have to check, and also I'm getting sometimes `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` which is hard to debug.

## ngDoCheck

That cycle hook I don't know. So cannot write anything.

Which method is best for handling Input change?